# django Arabic Hijri calendar

Tags: python, django, django-models

I use Django 2.2

When I have a field that has DateTimeField type, Django automatically uses Django calendar.

But in Saudi Arabia we use Islamic Hijri Calendar.

How can I define a field with Hijri calendar?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

First: I know this question is form a long time So please accept my apologies.

Second: I search before for this issue and found a very good library to use if you want to allow Hijri dates also the date picker for the administration panel.
to install it use below code

`pip install django-jalali-date`

For more information, you can check to [Github](https://github.com/a-roomana/django-jalali-date)

P.S. for converting dates you can use [hijri-converter](https://github.com/dralshehri/hijri-converter)